# Liferay 7: Sharing Content

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

I am new to Liferay and was wondering if the following use case is possible:

Use Case:
Share a piece of content in Site A with Site B.
   -  No Parent Child relationship between sites
   -  No Global Content
   -  The content to be shared is in Site A. 
   -  Site A is set up to share content at the site level.
   -  Want to add content to a page in Site B, not a site admin or site owner. Regular user. Page is set to be customized.

Have found ways to share some content with placing content in the global space, users having site admin role on both sites, subsites showing parent site content, but nothing that enables our use case to work.

Is this possible to achieve? If so, how?

Comment: What is specific business scenario which needs this?

Answer (score 0):

Not OOTB! The purpose of site is exactly to group (and eventually protect) content and pages. Unless you explicitly share the content (which is what global site is for) it is only available in the site it is defined. There are some other sharing options you've already discovered like parent-child sharing or site admin role sharing but no random sharing between sites.

That said, you can always extend Liferay and do this yourself, taking into account all the security issues and management overhead in introduces. If the content is public (or the user viewing it has the right permissions), you can use IFrame or call the respective jsonws service to get the content and display it.